# Keep a static graphic always fixed on screen while changing uiviews in xcode

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Is there any way to have a static graphic on screen that doesn't move when pushing / popping view controllers?

The best way I can think to describe this is like a tab bar.

If you have a tab on a tab bar that has multiple pages that swipe left/right, you can view these different pages, and only the main content area moves, while the tab bar stays fixed and doesn't swipe in/out along with the content.

I want to do something similar with a custom toolbar I have created and added to a view, but just now it slides out with the previous viewcontroller and then slides in with the new view controller.

Is there any way to keep that fixed on the screen so that it doesn't move.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Can you give me any example where its implemented in real app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using container view.

It is fairly new to XCode, so it doesn't have the widespread use that navigation controllers and tab bars do, but it works similarly.

Basically, You will create a new UIViewController instance in storyboard, and put a Container View inside the view controller, filling the entire view controller.  From there, you will right click on the view controller where your flow starts (probably either a tab bar controller or a navigation controller) select embed, and target the container view in your new view controller.  Finally, you'll need to change the initial view controller (the arrow that points to the first view controller the app should load) to this new UIViewController that has your container view.

If you run your app at this point, you should notice no difference at all.  The entire app is basically running inside the container view of that new view controller.  Now, you can a UIImageView to that new view controller anywhere you want.  Since the new view controller doesn't ever go away, the UIImageView you put inside it will stay there no matter what the container view is showing.

Hope this helps!

Note: I should add that if your program uses any modal transitions, that will cause the flow to exit the new view controller and it's container view as well, similar to how this affects tab bar controllers.